# Usage of setdefault instead of defaultdict

Tags: python

I need to create a structure like this :

```
D =  {i:{j:{k:0,l:1,m:2}},a:{b:{c:0,d:4}}}
```

So this can be done using defaultdict:

```
 D = defaultdict(defaultdict(Counter))
```

How do i use setdefault here?

EDIT :

Is it possible to combine setdefault and defaultdict ?

Comment: I think you meant `D = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(Counter))`?

Comment: BTW, why do you want to use `setdefault` instead of `defaultdict`?

Answer (score 0):

To build a multi-level dictionary with `setdefault()` you'd need to repeatedly access the keys like this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault("i", {}).setdefault("j", Counter())
Counter()
>>> d
{'i': {'j': Counter()}}
```

To generalize the usage for new keys you could use a function:

```
def get_counter(d, i, j):
    return d.setdefault(i, {}).setdefault(j, Counter())
```

Comment: I need to generalise the usage for new keys too...so how do i do that?